# To show specific university map using Google Maps

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-maps, maps

I want to show Particular University map using google maps. is there any way to particularly only to concentrate complete University.
please help me.

Answer (score 0):

check out the link it may be a proper answer for your question (http://www.gps-coordinates.net)
for location you need altitude and latitude you can find this from here 
http://www.gps-coordinates.net